# How to post selected values from multiple group of radio buttons which generated dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have below code which is generating radio button group list dynamically how can i pass those selected value to model?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Load", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (var p in Model.WeightBasedLoadModel.LoadParts)
    {

    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <legend>@p.SpeciesName @p.GradeName</legend>

        @for (var i = 0; i <= 100; i += 10)
        {
            decimal totalLbs = (decimal)i / (decimal)100 * (decimal)Model.WeightBasedLoadModel.NetLoadWeight;
            <input type="radio" name="percentage[@p.WeightBasedLoadPartID]" id="@p.WeightBasedLoadPartID-@i" class="required" value="@totalLbs.ToString()"><label for="@p.WeightBasedLoadPartID-@i">@i</label>if (i == 50)
                                                                                                                                                                                                              {<text><br /></text>}
        }
    </fieldset>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
}
```

Comment: Check this http://www.techiesweb.net/radio-button-list-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Do you mean the model when the form is posted to the server? Just have a model property that matches the name you've used for the input. The fact they're generated in a loop doesn't affect anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way -

Lets say you have a model like this -

```
public class MyClass1
{
    public List<List<string>> Cities { get; set; }
    public List<string> SelectedCity { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have a Controller action which will bind the initial data to a View-

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyClass1 c = new MyClass1();
        c.Cities = new List<List<string>>();


        List<string> first = new List<string>();
        first.Add("New York");
        first.Add("Los Angeles");
        c.Cities.Add(first);

        List<string> second = new List<string>();
        second.Add("New York1");
        second.Add("Los Angeles1");
        c.Cities.Add(second);

        return View(c);
    }
```

Then the view is going to be having a multiple RadioButton groups -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitData", "Radio", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    for(int j = 0; j < Model.Cities.Count; j++)
    {
        foreach (var i in Model.Cities[j])
        {
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(b => b.SelectedCity[j], i) @i
        }

    }

    <input type="submit" value="Click"/>
}
```

And When we click the Submit button, selected items of multiple Radiobutton groups will be posted to server in the List Property.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this i already know. please see my question again i have more than one radio button group list

Comment: @ArunRana Updated my answer. Please check. Let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

This way you will get the selected radio button values of the form

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()
```

make sure same name is used for set of radio elements so that all belong to a certain group

the return value from the above will the value of a selected radio button.

*Note: since the radio buttons are generated dynamically , you may need to use `.on` to associating the event with callback function(inside which you need to call the above line of code). **REF:http://api.jquery.com/on/***

Comment: Is there any way to pass in model?

Comment: I havent worked on asp.net mvc much, so better refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017037/could-not-pass-dropdownlist-selected-value-to-action-method. this may give you an idea how to pass the selected value to respective model via controller